# hardhat testing JavaScript got data from array via [ index ] instead of ( index )

Tags: javascript, etherscan, hardhat, testing

in javascript and in solidity if you need to get gata from array index you can write like that
`let data = array[ index ]`
but in the testing phase, i saw javascript got data from array like this `array ( index )`

> my array in solidity `address[] public funders;`

while testing in hardhat  via JS

```
 it("add funders to array funders array", async () => {
        await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
        let funder = await fundMe.funders(0)

        assert.equal(funder, deployer)
    })
```

as i know, in javascript and solidity, array works like that `array [ index ]` but how is this working. ?????
it shows error if i use `[ ]` to get data from array.

[image: image (6)]

Answer (score 2):

`funders` exactly is a function. Because you define `funders` in Solidity is public array, Solidity will auto generate a getter function for it with the same name like: `function funders(uint index) public returns (address)`. You can read more in [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/contracts.html#state-variable-visibility).